# Icon and text are not aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a card in Html and CSS and there are 2 icons in the bottom and one is on the left side and the other in the right side. The icons are correctly displayed but the text is not aligned in the middle. Does anyone has any tips or know how to make them aligned like icon (same line)---text align

HTML:

```
<div class="info-content">
    <div class="info left">
        <img src="./img/icon-ethereum.svg" alt=""><span class="text-info">0.041 ETH</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info right">
        <img src="./img/icon-clock.svg" alt=""><span class="text-info">3 days left</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.info-content {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: .7rem;
}

.info {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` and then `align-items: center` to vertically center the text and the icon.

```css
.info-content {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: .7rem;
}

.info {
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* added codes */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-content">
    <div class="info left">
     <img src="https://img.icons8.com/search" alt=""><span class="text-info">0.041 ETH</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info right">
     <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/apple-camera.png" alt=""><span class="text-info">3 days left</span>
    </div>
</div>
```